# Is there any repository with interval censored time-to-event datasets?

Tags: survival, dataset, mixture-distribution, threshold, interval-censoring

I'm looking for this particular structure of data for working on my thesis. In particular, I need interval censored with a cure fraction data. This kind is actually popular in medicine and clinical researches, but I'm having trouble finding them for analysis.

Interval censored consists in data where the time of an event is not directly observed, but it's known to belong to an interval (usually between two inspection points).

Cure rate means that there is a chance that the individual will never present the event of interest. In other words, the individual is unsusceptible or cured.

That said, does anyone knows any repository where I can find this kind of data, or any researcher looking for analysis, or any hint at least?

Thank you,
Julio

Answer (score 1):

I'm not aware of any repository but there are R (open source) packages, including the recommended `survival` package that have such datasets associated with worked examples. Doing a Google search with: "dataset interval-censored" brings up another R package, `interval` by the well-respected Michael Fay at NIH and other links to SAS code with examples and examples using the KMsurv package in R.